# Longest Run Program In Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a school assignment where i have to find the longest run of adjacent equal characters in a given string with Ruby. My program works fine without the last loop, but once i added it gave me the error:

```
(repl):47: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
(repl):53: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
puts longestRun
               ^
```

Here is my Code

```
puts 'What is your string?'
givenString = gets.chomp

def maxBlock(str)  
  maxRun = 0  
  currentRun = 1  
  characterCounter = 1

  if str.length == 0
    maxRun = 0
    #If no input, longest run is zero

  elsif str.length == 1  
    maxRun = 1
    #If string is one character, longest run is 1

  elsif str.length == 2 and str[characterCounter] != str[characterCounter + 1]
    maxRun = 1
    #if string is two chars and they do not equal, longest run is 1

  elsif str.length == 3 and str[0] != str[1] and str[1] != str[2]
    maxRun = 1
    #if string is three chars and they do not equal, longest run is 1

  else
    str.each_char do|st|
      #Go through each char, compare it to the next, find longest run
      if st == str[characterCounter]
        currentRun++
        if currentRun > maxRun
          maxRun = currentRun
        end
      else
        currentRun = 1
      end
      characterCounter++
    end
  end
end
longestRun = maxBlock(givenString)
puts longestRun
```

EDIT: I am a highschool student, and only have a base knowledge of programming.

EDIT: I just made a few stupid mistakes. I appreciate everyone's help. Here is my working program without the use of anything too complicated.

```
puts 'What is your string?'
givenString = gets.chomp

def maxBlock(str)  
  maxRun = 0  
  currentRun = 1  
  characterCounter = 0

  if str.length == 0
    maxRun = 0
    #If no input, longest run is zero

  elsif str.length == 1  
    maxRun = 1
    #If string is one character, longest run is 1

  elsif str.length == 2 and str[characterCounter] != str[characterCounter + 1]
    maxRun = 1
    #if string is two chars and they do not equal, longest run is 1

  elsif str.length == 3 and str[0] != str[1] and str[1] != str[2]
    maxRun = 1
    #if string is three chars and they do not equal, longest run is 1

  else  
    characterCounter += 1
    str.each_char do|st|
      #Go through each char, compare it to the next, find longest run
      if st == str[characterCounter]
        currentRun += 1
        if currentRun > maxRun
          maxRun = currentRun
        end
      else
        currentRun = 1
      end
      characterCounter += 1
    end
  end
return maxRun
end
longestRun = maxBlock(givenString)
puts longestRun
```

Comment: you are getting the error because you can't do `characterCounter++` in ruby, you have to do `characterCounter += 1`

Comment: Please put in the effort to make your question readable. The formatting isn't correct. Consider this, you're asking for help solving the question on a public site that is well know by educators. Do you really want to ask for a solution here?

Comment: It appears you posted the question, left and have not been back since. Why ask SO members to spend time helping you if you're not even going to read their answers?

Comment: I am new to Ruby, and this website. This is an attempt to recreate a working program I created using java. I apologize for the formatting issues, and my lack of knowledge on ruby syntax. As for the lack of my participation, I have been away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version that should work in all cases:

```
puts 'What is your string?'
given_string = gets.chomp

def max_block(str)  
  max_run = 0
  current_run = 1

  str.each_char.with_index do |st, idx|
    if st == str[idx + 1]
      current_run += 1
    else
      current_run = 1
    end

    max_run = current_run if current_run > max_run
  end

  max_run
end

longest_run = max_block(given_string)
puts longest_run
```

You were on the right track but Ruby can make things a lot easier for you. Notice how `with_index` gets rid of a lot of the complexity. Iterators, oh yeah.

I also changed your method name and variables to camel_case.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

### String Scans and Sorting

There are algorithms for this, but Ruby offers some nice shortcuts. For example:

```
def longest_string str
  str.scan(/((\p{Alnum})\2+)/).collect { |grp1, grp2| grp1 }.sort_by(&:size).last
end

longest_string 'foo baaar quuuux'
#=> "uuuu"
```

This basically just captures all runs of repeated characters, sorts the captured substrings by length, and then returns the last element of the length-sorted array.

### Secondary Sorting

If you want to do a secondary sort, such as first by length and then by alphabetical order, you could replace [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort-by) with the block form of [Enumerable#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort). For example:

```
def longest_string str
  str.scan(/((\p{Alnum})\2+)/).
    collect { |grp1, grp2| grp1 }.
    sort {|a, b| [a.size, a] <=> [b.size, b] }.
    last
end

longest_string 'foo quux baar'
#=> "uu"
```

Comment: In `longest_string` you can replace `sort` with `max` (but keep the block) and drop `last`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could do it.

```
str = "111 wwwwwwwwaabbbbbbbbbbb$$$$****"

r = /
    (.) # Match any character in capture group 1
    \1* # Match the contents of capture group 1 zero or more times
    /x  # Free-spacing regex definition mode

str.gsub(r).max_by(&:size)
  #=> "bbbbbbbbbbb"
```

I used the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) without a second argument or block, as that returns an enumerator that generates the strings matched by the regex. I then chained that enumerator to the method [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to find the longest string of consecutive characters. In other words, I used `gsub` merely to generate matches rather than to perform substitutions.

One could of course write `str.gsub(/(.)\1*/).max_by(&:size)`.

Comment: My initial intention was to use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan). The problem is (from the doc) "If the pattern contains [capture] groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group" and of course a capture group is necessary for the back-reference. I'd be interested if any reader could suggest how `scan` could be used here, if that is possible.

Comment: @seph, excellent suggestion! Many thanks. I've incorporated it into my answer (of course). btw, I know many here include attributions in answers, but I like to keep answers clean (and wish everyone did), so I use a comment for that.

Comment: You can use scan like this: `str.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first).max_by(&:size)`

Comment: Thanks, @Addison. I actually tried that but didn't recognize that what I needed was in the returned array.

Comment: This is a clever answer. The use of gsub is effective but not intuitive. :) No bike-shedding intended, but this has the same problem as my answer before adding a secondary sort: consider what the "correct" result should be given `foo bar quux`.

Comment: @CodeGnome, I was not familiar with the expression "bike-shedding", so [looked it up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding). Interesting!